# Import MySQL data failed with error 1839

Tags: import, mysql, gtid

I have master slave setup of MySQL with GTID configured. I took back data backup of master and importing it to individual Test server. It is failing to import as

> ERROR 1839 (HY000) at line 24: @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED can only be set
>   when @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON

I tried with `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` and `AUTO`, but no luck.

Comment: Should this be in "superuser"?

Comment: ok i do create their i am not sure i can move from this site to that site directly.. for this time i am copy paste :)

Comment: I mean shouldn't this be posted on stack overflows "superuser" site.

Comment: NO MAN I DID GOOGLE SEARCH IT DIDN'T COME UP

Comment: What I mean is http://superuser.com/  I think it's all server side issues.

Comment: found solultion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38129690/944593

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud sql database export import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123263/cloud-sql-database-export-import-issue)