# Cloud sql database export import issue

Tags: google-cloud-sql

When exporting an sql database from an instance (2nd gen) and importing it on another sql instance, I get the following error: 
ERROR 1839 (HY000) at line 24:

```
@@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED can only be set when @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON.
```

According to https://superuser.com/questions/906843/import-mysql-data-failed-with-error-1839 this could be solved by making an sql dump with

```
--set-gtid-purged=OFF
```

But the gcloud sql instances export command does not support this. Is there another way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 25):

(In an SQL Editor) run `RESET MASTER` on the database you're importing to.

> issuing RESET MASTER resets the GTID execution history.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reset-master.html

Comment: This is a good option that does not involve creating the dump file all over again (an hour and ten minutes) or needing to manually edit a 200G dump file.

Comment: just run this , RESET MASTER; where you want to import . that's it.  It solved my problem.

Comment: The issue relates to CloudSQL in MySQL mode, however as CloudSQL only provides users with accounts with limited permissions (as it is as DBaaS), `RESET MASTER;` fails with `Access denied; you need (at least one of) the REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation`.

Answer (score 11):

would you try the following two ways?

Option 1) Remove this line from the sql dump file, and import it to your database?
`SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED='1b313522-1ee5-11e6-9c51-0242ac110003:1-2020';`

Option 2) turn off binary logging on your instance, then do the export?

Reference [Article](https://itectec.com/superuser/import-mysql-data-failed-with-error-1839/)

Comment: I tried option 1, and that works, but the problem is that I export the dump in gz format to cloud storage. If I wanted to edit the file I would need to download it, decompress it, edit the line, compress it and upload it again. Is there an easier way?
Option 2 is not preferred because we don't want to disable replication.

Comment: worked like a charm! thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can run `reset master` on the database that you are using to solve this, worked for me

Comment: This works. However I would really appreciate if you can add what actually this query does.

Comment: @JitheshKt Same here

Answer (score 1):

> We have found the below error
>
> ERROR 3546 (HY000) at line 24: @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED cannot be changed:
> the added gtid set must not overlap with @@GLOBAL.GTID_EXECUTED

> We have import the DB after the login MySQL connect from the command line
> Then after using the below command to import

> mysql> SOURCE stagingdump.sql

I did not say this is the best way but I have resolved my error this way.